# Search an element in Arraylist where it's contains some element

Tags: java, algorithm, search, arraylist, find

I need help. Would you give me solution how to fix my code?
I have an arraylist where each contains some element. And I want to use search method to find it by just one element keyword.

This the code to add

```
System.out.print("ID_Cargo >> ");
ID_Cargo=scan.next();
System.out.print("No_Container >> ");
No_Container=scan.next();
CARGO.add(new CARGO(ID_Cargo,No_Container));
```

And this is to search

```
String find;
System.out.println("ID Cargo : ");
find=scan.next();
if(CARGO.contains(find)){
   System.out.println("FOUND");
}
else{
   System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
}
```

the search is always return Not found but the element what I find is exist. How to fix it in order to return FOUND?
Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list `CARGO` contains not `String`s but `CARGO` instances (*you should really rename your list to avoid confusion!*). Because of that fact you need to search with a `CARGO` instances not with a String.

`CARGO.contains(find)`

should be

`CARGO.contains(new CARGO(find, null)  // because you search for the ID the second argument is empty`

2. You need to write an `equals` method in your CARGO class which only compared the `ID`

That should work.

But if you want to search often, you should consider a `Map` instead of a `List`.

*P.s. I cannot provide concrete code, because I do not know exactly how your class looks like*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `CARGO` list contains `CARGO` objects (not a good idea to use the same name), but you are checking if a String (`find`) is contained in that List, which naturally returns false.

If you wish to search for a `CARGO` instance by its identifier, a `HashMap<String,CARGO>` would be more suitable.

```
Map<String,CARGO> cargoMap = new HashMap<>();
cargoMap.put(ID_Cargo,new CARGO(ID_Cargo,No_Container));
...
if(cargoMap.containsKey(find)){
    System.out.println("FOUND");
} else {
    System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
}
```

EDIT:

To display the properties of the `CARGO` isntance having the `find` key (assuming your `CARGO` class has such getter methods) :

```
CARGO cargo = cargoMap.get(find);
if (cargo != null) {
    System.out.println("FOUND: " + cargo.getCargoID() + " " + cargo.getContainerNo());
} else {
    System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, ur answer is very useful. But I wanna ask you again. Can you change the return from "FOUND" to value of ID_Cargo and No_Container?

Answer (score 0):

your CARGO list has objects of Cargo,  and you're trying to find a "String" in that list, that is why you are getting Not Found. use a loop instead: 
this is a metod that takes a list and ID and return true if a cargo with that ID exist, otherwise false

```
public boolean isExist(ArrayLisr<Cargo> CARGO , String ID) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < CARGO.size(); i++){
          Cargo cargo = CARGO.get(i);
          if( cargo.getID.equals(ID)
                 return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

the method .get(i) returns the object in the list that is in the position i, the method .size() returns the number of objects in that list
the method .getID is a method you should create in your Cargo class, and make it return the ID

Basically, this method takes the objects in the list one by one, check if that object has the ID we want or not, return true if it has it, go to the other object otherwise. if we reached the end of the list and none of the objects in that list returned true, that means no object with that ID is exist, so return false